# Deadlock using channels as queues

Tags: go, deadlock, jobs, channel, worker

I'm learning Go and I am trying to implement a job queue.

What I'm trying to do is:

Have the main goroutine feed lines through a channel for multiple parser workers (that parse a line to s struct), and have each parser send the struct to a channel of structs that other workers (goroutines) will process (send to database, etc).

The code looks like this:

```
lineParseQ := make(chan string, 5)
jobProcessQ := make(chan myStruct, 5)
doneQ := make(chan myStruct, 5)

fileName := "myfile.csv"

file, err := os.Open(fileName)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

defer file.Close()

reader := bufio.NewReader(file)

// Start line parsing workers and send to jobProcessQ
for i := 1; i <= 2; i++ {
    go lineToStructWorker(i, lineParseQ, jobProcessQ)
}

// Process myStruct from jobProcessQ
for i := 1; i <= 5; i++ {
    go WorkerProcessStruct(i, jobProcessQ, doneQ)
}

lineCount := 0 
countSend := 0

for {
    line, err := reader.ReadString('\n')
    
    if err != nil && err != io.EOF {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    
    if err == io.EOF {
        break
    }
    
    lineCount++
    
    if lineCount > 1 {
        countSend++
        lineParseQ <- line[:len(line)-1]    // Avoid last char '\n'
    }

}

for i := 0; i < countSend; i++ {
    fmt.Printf("Received %+v.\n", <-doneQ)
}

close(doneQ)
close(jobProcessQ)
close(lineParseQ)
```

Here's a simplified playground: https://play.golang.org/p/yz84g6CJraa

the workers look like this:

```
func lineToStructWorker(workerID int, lineQ <-chan string, strQ chan<- myStruct ) {

    for j := range lineQ {
        strQ <- lineToStruct(j) // just parses the csv to a struct...
    }

}

func WorkerProcessStruct(workerID int, strQ <-chan myStruct, done chan<- myStruct) {

    for a := range strQ {
        time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 500) // fake long operation...
        done <- a
    }
}
```

I know the problem is related to the "done" channel because if I don't use it, there's no error, but I can't figure out how to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't *start* reading from `doneQ` until you've finished sending *all* the lines to `lineParseQ`, which is more lines than there is buffer space. So once the `doneQ` buffer is full, that send blocks, which starts filling the `lineParseQ` buffer, and once that's full, it deadlocks. Move either the loop sending to `lineParseQ`, the loop reading from `doneQ`, or both, to separate goroutine(s), e.g.:

```
go func() {
    for _, line := range lines {
        countSend++
        lineParseQ <- line
    }
    close(lineParseQ)
}()
```

This will still deadlock at the end, because you've got a `range` over a channel and the `close` after it in the same goroutine; since `range` continues until the channel is closed, and the close comes after the `range` finishes, you still have a deadlock. You need to put the closes in appropriate places; that being, either in the sending routine, or blocked on a `WaitGroup` monitoring the sending routines if there are multiple senders for a given channel.

```
// Start line parsing workers and send to jobProcessQ
wg := new(sync.WaitGroup)
for i := 1; i <= 2; i++ {
    wg.Add(1)
    go lineToStructWorker(i, lineParseQ, jobProcessQ, wg)
}

// Process myStruct from jobProcessQ
for i := 1; i <= 5; i++ {
    go WorkerProcessStruct(i, jobProcessQ, doneQ)
}

countSend := 0

go func() {
    for _, line := range lines {
        countSend++
        lineParseQ <- line
    }
    close(lineParseQ)
}()

go func() {
    wg.Wait()
    close(jobProcessQ)
}()

for a := range doneQ {
    fmt.Printf("Received %v.\n", a)
}

// ...

func lineToStructWorker(workerID int, lineQ <-chan string, strQ chan<- myStruct, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    for j := range lineQ {
        strQ <- lineToStruct(j) // just parses the csv to a struct...
    }
    wg.Done()
}

func WorkerProcessStruct(workerID int, strQ <-chan myStruct, done chan<- myStruct) {
    for a := range strQ {
        time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 500) // fake long operation...
        done <- a
    }
    close(done)
}
```

Full working example here: https://play.golang.org/p/XsnewSZeb2X

Comment: Thanks! I added a longer buffer (15) for lineParseQ and jobProcessQ, and after removing the sleep I keep getting deadlocked... The concrete example has hundreds of thousands of lines, and I plan to use something like 50 goroutines

Comment: This solution exits before all the results are processed.

Comment: @Luis increasing the buffer size generally doesn't solve anything. You just need to manage the concurrency effectively. As colm pointed out I still had an error - I didn't notice there's multiple `WorkerProcessStruct` workers, so it needs the same `WaitGroup` setup used for `lineToStructWorker`. I updated the Playground example to fix that issue and it now processes all entries: https://play.golang.org/p/XsnewSZeb2X

Answer (score 2):

Coordinate the pipeline with `sync.WaitGroup` breaking each piece into stages. When you know one piece of the pipeline is complete (and no one is writing to a particular channel), close the channel to instruct all "workers" to exit e.g.

```
var wg sync.WaitGroup
for i := 1; i <= 5; i++ {
    i := i
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        Worker(i)
        wg.Done()
    }()
}

// wg.Wait() signals the above have completed
```

Buffered channels are handy to handle burst workloads, but sometimes they are used to avoid deadlocks in poor designs. If you want to avoid running certain parts of your pipeline in a goroutine you can buffer some channels (matching the number of workers typically) to avoid a blockage in your main goroutine.

If you have dependent pieces that read & write and want to avoid deadlock - ensure they are in separate goroutines. Having all parts of the pipeline it its own goroutine will even remove the need for buffered channels:

```
// putting all channel work into separate goroutines
// removes the need for buffered channels
lineParseQ := make(chan string, 0)
jobProcessQ := make(chan myStruct, 0)
doneQ := make(chan myStruct, 0)
```

Its a tradeoff of course - a goroutine costs about 2K in resources - versus a buffered channel which is much less. As with most designs it depends on how it is used.

Also don't get caught by the notorious Go [for-loop gotcha](https://yourbasic.org/golang/gotcha-data-race-closure/), so use a closure assignment to avoid this:

```
for i := 1; i <= 5; i++ {
    i := i       // new i (not the i above)
    go func() {
        myfunc(i) // otherwise all goroutines will most likely get '5'
    }()
}
```

Finally ensure you wait for all results to be processed before exiting.
It's a common mistake to return from a channel based function and believe all results have been processed. In a service this will eventually be true. But in a standalone executable the processing loop may still be working on results.

```
go func() {
    wgW.Wait()   // waiting on worker goroutines to finish
    close(doneQ) // safe to close results channel now
}()

// ensure we don't return until all results have been processed
for a := range doneQ {
    fmt.Printf("Received %v.\n", a)
}
```

by processing the results in the main goroutine, we ensure we don't return prematurely without having processed everything.

Pulling it all together:

https://play.golang.org/p/MjLpQ5xglP3

Comment: There's no race on `go myfunc(i)` here because the arguments to `myfunc` get evaluated before the call spawns the new goroutine. The race occurs with `go func() { use(i) }()` because the empty parens after the `func() { ... }` sequence mean that *no* arguments get evaluated; the `use(i)` uses the closure `i`. But `go myfunc(i)` causes the `i` to get evaluated and there's no closure variable passed through.

Comment: (That's pretty minor, though, and doesn't actually introduce any bug.)

Comment: Ah yes indeed!  I must have been projecting after adding the sync.WaitGroup logic & switched to using anonymous functions.